# Mysql syntax error while encrypting input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to insert a new row to mysql database with php.

**password is blob** I have tried both `s` and `b` for password in `bind_param`

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS (email,password,key) VALUES (?,AES_ENCRYPT(?, ?),?)");
            if ( !$stmt ) {
             echo "prepare failed\n";
            echo "error: ", $this->db->error, "\n";
             return;
            }

            $rc = $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $email, $password, $key, $key);
            if ( !$rc ) {
              echo "bind_param failed\n";
              echo "error: ", $stmt->error, "\n";
              return;
         }
```

**error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES (?,AES_ENCRYPT(?, ?),?)' at line 1**

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are encrypting and not hashing your passwords? Hashing is more secure as its one way, and you should never need to decrypt the password.

Comment: If multiple users choose same password hash will be the same isnt it? well i thought key will be unique for each users so it will be safe enough for everyone

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The point of hashing the password is so that if your database is compromised you can't recover the password. With an encryption key stored with the user information you can. If you try to enforce unique passwords you reveal to a user that someone is using the password. Its a matter of brute force to figure out who.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in mysql. you'll have to quote it:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, password, `key`) ...
                                    ^---^--
```

on the logistical front, what's the point of encrypting the password if you're storing the crypt key right there next to it? it'd be like a bank building a vault with 50' thick steel walls, then using a bit of chewing gum to "lock" the door.

Comment: More like putting the combination on a Post-It next to the lock.

Comment: I wont store key in database I am just trying to see if that encryption is working or not.